# Visible to only some people on Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, instant-messaging

I am afraid of using whatsapp just to avoid so many unwanted messages or unnecessary people contacting you. Just wondering, is it possible that am visible on whatsapp to ONLY some people (all my contacts shouldn't come to know)?

Comment: What is your phone model and Android version?

Comment: You [mention on a comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126381/visible-to-only-some-people-on-whatsapp#comment156465_126389) that `Actually, i have windows phone`... so, you're on the wrong channel

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can choose the option to be visible only to your contacts.

Go to **Settings --> Account --> Privacy --> Who can see my personal info** and choose Last seen, Profile photo, status to `My contacts`. But configuring this, everyone who is not in your address list can know that you have a WhatsApp account, but they cannot see your last seen, profile photo, status.  You can also **block** unwanted contacts here. By blocking a particular contact, the other side will not see your last seen, profile photo, status and additionally you will not receive any messages / calls from blocked contact, messages will be shown as undelivered to them.

When you are in a group, provided you set the correct privacy options, the group members can only see your `number` and the `name` that you used while adding account on the device. There is no way to change this behavior.

Also, you cannot avoid unknown users adding you to a group. WhatsApp doesn't ask you whether you wanted to join a group or not. All you can do is to quit after joining and block the ones that joined you. **Blocked contacts** couldn't add you to a group.

Comment: Actually, i have windows phone. I have set "noone" in privacy for profile, status & picture yet my contact can see. Can't I avoid it?

Comment: I don't own a windows phone. It could be a bug. I see you have asked in Windows Phone section as well. You may report to whatsapp about this.. Mail to `support@whatsapp.com`

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp needs the users mobile number to add someone, so I guess don't give your mobiles number to everyone and if someone got your number and is trying to give you unwanted messages then just block 'em.

Comment: I don't share or add someone to my phone contacts just like that! I have to  be on certain WhatsApp group to receive some updates however, I don't want all my contact to know about it. Looks like WhatsApp doesn't have support it yet. Right?

Comment: Blocking is not practical so it is "per user". People won't be able to send you msgs on WhatsApp but they'll come to know you're on WhatsApp.

Comment: so can it be like that the groups are sending you unwanted messages cause thats what happened to me.

Comment: There're ppl who are ready to create group & simply add u without your permission. Just want to avoid it.

Comment: Then simply long press on the group and delete it.

Comment: yea, I am aware. Wish WhatsApp feature which allow you to make urself visible only to few people in your contact